# With RxJS 6, how do I re-emit values from observed arrays, with a delay between each/all values?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

At regular intervals, I want to poll an API that will return an array of records which will almost certainly vary in size. I want each record to display in a CSS animation which takes *t* amount of time. Therefore, I must buffer the API responses and release them individually, no more frequently than *t*, so that the animation can complete smoothly.

After much searching and trial and error, I put together this custom RxJS operator (in framework-less TypeScript). However, the double/nested `concatMap` has a bit of code smell. Is there a more elegant or reactive solution? Are all the inner observables managed properly (unsubscribed from)?

(This is my first custom operator, so any other feedback is welcome.)

```js
export function recordPace (/* params to pipe */): OperatorFunction<IRecord[], IRecord> {
    // inner function automatically receives source observable
    return (source: Observable<IRecord[]>) => {
        return source.pipe(
            // First, explode the array to show one at a time.
            concatMap((records: IRecord[]) => from(records).pipe(
                // Now, for each array value, add a delay
                concatMap((record: IRecord) => of(record).pipe(
                    delay(t),
                ))
                tap((record: IRecord) => {
                    // executes once per record, no faster than every t
                }),
            )),
            tap((record: IRecord) => {
                // alternative also executes once per record, no faster than every t
            }),
        );
    };
}
```

```js
MyApi.doPolling().pipe(
    recordPace(),
    recordAnimate(),
).subscribe(
    () => {},
    () => {},
    () => { console.log('done'); }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *explode* the array, you can use `mergeAll()`.

```js
export function recordPace (/* params to pipe */): OperatorFunction<IRecord[], IRecord> {
  return (source: Observable<IRecord[]>) => {
    return source.pipe(
      // concatMap((records: IRecord[]) => from(records).pipe(
      mergeAll(),
      concatMap((record: IRecord) => of(record).pipe(
        delay(t),
      ))
      tap((record: IRecord) => {
        // executes once per record, no faster than every t
      }),
      // )),
      tap((record: IRecord) => {}),
    );
  };
}
```

You can use any of the `mergeAll`, `switchAll`, `concatAll` operators. This is because if you only want to *explode* the array, there is no async operation involved. Each operator mentioned above takes in a function that returns an [`ObservableInput`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/types.ts#L96)

```js
export type ObservableInput<T> = Observable<T> | InteropObservable<T> | AsyncIterable<T> | PromiseLike<T> | ArrayLike<T> | Iterable<T>;
```

As you can see, an array could be considered an `ObservableInput` and the behaviour is that if your callback function returns an array, it will send each of its items individually.

Also, congrats on your first custom operator!

Comment: In other words, `mergeAll`, `switchAll`, `concatAll` are equivalent *in this case* because an array's synchronous "atomicity" means there's no way for elements of the nth emitted array to intermix with elements of array 1 through n-1.

Comment: @nshew13 Yes, exactly!